# Quiero insertar un dato de una tabla a otra en sql realizado un insert select pero la verificacion de usuario no me permite realizarlo

Tags: mysql, sql

intente realizarlo con el siguiente codigo pero debido a que el dato es auto incremental y llave primaria no es posible

```
INSERT into estudiante (trabajo, ID_estudiante) SELECT ID_trabajo, ID_estudiante from trabajo, estudiante WHERE trabajo.titulo = 'seguimiento de trabajo de grado' and estudiante.ID_estudiante = 7;
```

debido a que debo verificar donde se esta insertando el dato ya que son asignaciondes de TRabajos, no me permiten realizar el insert nose como solucionarlo ya que debo verificar el usuario.
REVISANDO EL CODIGO NOTE QUE ESTA FUNCION APARENTEMENTE NO ALTERA LOS REGISTRO YA REALIZADOS SINO QUE CREA NUEVOS SI ALGUIEN ME BRINDASE UNA FUNCION QUE ME PERMITA ALTERAR UN REGISTRO YA REALIZADO EJEMPLO:
TENGO EN UNA TABLA ESTUDIANTE id, nombre, codigo Y trabajo <- al cual LE QUIERO ASIGNAR EL id DE LA TABLA TRABAJO QUE SE REGISTRA POSTERIORMENTE.

Comment: ¿qué dato especificamente es autoincremental? ¿qué significa, en otras palabras "verificar el usuario"?

Comment: el ID_usuario es auto incremental ya que creo los estudiantes primero y luego quiero asignarles los trabajos

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, sugiero que leas [ask]. Incluye la estructura de la(s) tabla(s) relacionadas, una explicación completa de lo que quieres lograr y de lo que has intentado o los problemas que te está dando lo que has hecho hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione:

```
UPDATE estudiante est JOIN trabajo trab ON trab.titulo = 'seguimiento de trabajo de grado' and est.ID_estudiante = 7 SET est.trabajo = trab.ID_trabajo;
```

buscando me tope con este video que aclaro mi duda se los dejo por si les interesa: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSH-cyY26Eo